# In Windows 10, what is the best way to attribute the character ß to AltGr+S key combination?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My keyboard is not German but as I'm writing some German texts, I would like to be able to write the character ß with that key combination. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Windows Language Preferences

Windows allows you to add extra keyboard layouts. You can type **Add a language to this device** into the Start search. Once you have another keyboard layout installed, you can swap between them with **Alt+Shift**.

## 2. AutoHotkey

[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) allows you to redefine any set of keystrokes to perform any action you want. Text replacement is the simplest example of what you can do with it.
A working script should look like:

```
<^>!s:*:ß
```

Where <^> stands for the AltGr modifier, and :*: denotes replacement (will not leave behind an *s*).

Comment: I would add that the keyboard language one wants to use is: US International. It will give ß when you press alt-gr + S, similar to € when you press alt-gr + 5 or ® when you press alt-gr + r, etc...

Answer (score 0):

One way I have found is to use the `Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator` which is available for free.

It is easy is to use: I just loaded the layout of my German keyboard and added the - in my very case - missing Spanish characters in combination with <kbd>ALT GR</kbd>.

Then I have created an installer for a new keyboard driver with a few clicks. After installing that customized keyboard I can add use it in Windows 10 just as any other keyboard driver.

From the screenshots you can see another detail: There is an **US-INTERNATIONAL keyboard** already existing. You can also try this as it might suits your needs.

[image: Keyboard layout editor]
[image: Keyboard in windows]
[image: Add keyboard]

Related to: [How can I define my own ALT GR + n combination (German KB) to display ñ?](https://superuser.com/q/1664800/72397)