# How can I define my own ALT GR + n combination (German KB) to display ñ?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

How can I define that a symbol is displayed for a particular <kbd>ALT GR</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> combination? More precisely, I want to define that <kbd>ALT GR</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> displays the `ñ` symbol/character. I am using a German keyboard.

This [article here](https://www.theverge.com/22351023/windows-pc-special-characters-how-to) shows several options. The best at the moment is to use the `EMOJI KEYBOARD` - but is always opens with the emoji page and not the symbol page and requires multiple clicks (otherwise it would be a "good" option).

I am using a laptop, so I have **NO** numpad to enter the Unicode value. Changing the Windows language preference as in https://superuser.com/a/1250523/72397 is **NO** option for me. If possible I want to avoid 3rd party software.

For US the US international keyboard layout exists, [see here](https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/keyboard-shortcuts-for-typing-accent-marks-over-letters-in-windows-10?from=Settings&OCID=LanguageSettings). Unfortunately there is no GERMAN international layout :-(

Related to:

- [What's the function of the Alt Gr key?](https://superuser.com/q/220071/72397)
- [In Windows 10, what is the best way to attribute the character ß to AltGr+S key combination?](https://superuser.com/q/1250517/72397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I have found is to use the `Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator` which is available for free.

It is easy is to use: I just loaded the layout of my German keyboard and added the missing Spanish characters in combination with <kbd>ALT GR</kbd>.

Then I have created an installer for a new keyboard driver with a few clicks. After installing that customized keyboard I can add use it in Windows 10 just as any other keyboard driver.

[image: Keyboard layout editor]

[image: Keyboard in windows]

[image: Add keyboard]